# Discord.py - Temporary voice channels

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this code for creating temporary voice channels on my Discord server. Temporary voice channel is created in the same category where is "template channel" located. I am trying to have implemented some features, which create temporary channel in different category and assign channel number before name of channel. Bot will check numbers starting with number 1 and create new channel with first available number. So if I have 10 channels and number 7 is available, bot will create channel with number 7 and fit between 6 and 8 (If it is even possible?)

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member:discord.Member, before:discord.VoiceState, after:discord.VoiceState):
        alMazrah_duo_name = f"{member.name}'s Duo"

        if after.channel:
            # DUO CHANNELS
            if after.channel.id == settings.ALMAZRAH_TEMPLATE_DUO_ID:
                temp_channel = await after.channel.clone(name=alMazrah_duo_name)
                await member.move_to(temp_channel)
                self.temp_channels.append(temp_channel.id)
        
        if before.channel:
            if before.channel.id in self.temp_channels:
                if len(before.channel.members) == 0:
                    await before.channel.delete()
```

Could you please help?

About creating of channel in different category I tried:

```
temp_channel = await after.channel.clone(name="temp_channel_name", category_name="Category Name")
```

Comment: You've outlined what you want the code to do, what does it _currently_ do? What doesn't seem to be working as expected?

Comment: My bot is currently creating temporary voice channel in the same category where is template channel located. So if I have template channel in category "Join to Create", new temporary room is created in the same category. But I would like to create this channel in "Duo Voice Channel" category, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`clone`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.clone) method doesn't take a `category` parameter so that won't work. We can either just `clone` the channel and then [*move*](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.move) it to another category - or we can create a new channel under the other category.

Here's the move method:

```py
guild = after.guild
category = await guild.fetch_channel(CATEGORY_CHANNEL_ID)
cloned_channel = await after.channel.clone(name="temp_channel_name")
await closed_channel.move(category=category)
```

*Or*, if you want to [create the channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.create_voice_channel) directly in the category:

```py
guild = after.guild
category = await guild.fetch_channel(CATEGORY_CHANNEL_ID)
temp_channel = await category.create_voice_channel(name="test name")
```

With regards to the other part of your question; if you get the [category](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel) then you can iteratve over the [`voice_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.voice_channels) property to get all the voice channels in it. You can then check each voice channel's names for the numbers.